# Swift - Many IBOutlets one controller

Tags: ios, iboutlet

I have a view controller where i need to have almost 200 textfields.
I'm, building an energy consumption calculator and i need to give the user the possibility to add all the field he could be interested in...

My question is:
will it give problems when it comes to memory usage and performance?
is there a better way to add 200 Outlets to collect the text insert by the user?

Comment: You should probably use `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` with text fields inside the cell. They implement reusability. 200 text fields displayed at once will have some performance impact.

Comment: my issue is that i use all the fields to perform some math... i'm not sure if is possible to do so if i use a collection view...

Comment: Even when using 200 textfields, I guess you are storing the input values in some sort of data structure and don't just work directly with the textfields' text property. With the same approach, you can persist the user input from all tableview/collectionview cells as well, even if some of them is not visible on screen and hence they have been reused by the system.

Comment: Just to emphasize what @DávidPásztor says: this is why people separate the UI and the data model; the UI can change without you having to modify the calculation logic if they are independent of each other.

Comment: using core data.... but this is just a calculator so not storing the values... anyway i guess using a tableview is a good way... o probably i could create subviews... thx! :)

Comment: @Marco I didn't mean you have to persist the data on storage. Even just storing the values of the textfields' in a simple Array would help.

Comment: @DávidPásztor sorry probably i haven't understand... i'm creating something like this: http://prntscr.com/fx72ev. Users put some values and automatically get a results....u're suggesting to store values in an array and perform the math using the array?

Comment: If I get what you have said so far correctly, at the moment you are doing all calculations directly on `someTextField.text` values, meaning that you don't store user input anywhere (either in memory or on storage), you just use the user input directly to do some calculations and show the results on UI. What I am proposing is to store the data in any kind of data structure (Array was just the simplest example) that fits your needs and hence separate the UI and data model. This makes your code more reusable and easier to change the UI or model independent of each other.

Comment: @DávidPásztor so basically i create a model where i store all the data and then use them on UI... great!! didn't think about it bust seems a great solution! Thx! :)

Comment: @Marco yes, that's it. You should have a look at the [Model-View-Controller or MVC as short](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) design pattern as this is the basic idea behind it and it is common practice in iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` with one `UITextField` in each cell. Once the user starts typing you can store the value, for instance:

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    private var values: [Int]?

    // code for reuse the cell
    // ............

    // you can use UITextFieldDelegate, store the index the user is at...
    // the logic is up to you
    func userTappedSomething() {
        values?.append(Int(currentFocusedCell.myTextField.text))
    }
}
```

This logic may vary since you can store the current index path you're at or even the current text being typed so the logic is up to you but the idea is to store each value you tap in a sequence so you "navigate" in your UI and be able to call `cellForRow` and set the value stored back.

About the text field, you can use a tag or create a custom cell with an `IBOutlet` and access directly.

**WARNING: Untested code**